# Time formatting for org clocktable report

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-clock table to track time. It is more convenient for me to see time in hours, not in days. How could I configure org clocktable to do that?

Here is what I get now:

```
* A
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2020-05-08 Fri 10:37]--[2020-05-08 Fri 23:37] => 13:00
  CLOCK: [2020-05-07 Thu 13:37]--[2020-05-07 Thu 23:37] => 10:00
  :END:
* D
  :LOGBOOK:
  CLOCK: [2020-05-08 Fri 03:37]--[2020-05-08 Fri 05:37] =>  2:00
  CLOCK: [2020-05-06 Thu 03:37]--[2020-05-06 Thu 05:37] =>  2:00
  :END:


#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 2
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2020-05-08 Fri 19:40]
| Headline     |      Time |
|--------------+-----------|
| *Total time* | *1d 3:00* |
|--------------+-----------|
| A            |     23:00 |
| D            |      4:00 |
#+END:
```

Note "Total time" is "1d 3:00". I want total time to be shown as 27:00.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time format is controller by the variable `org-duration-format` which has a very long description (`C-h v org-duration-format RET`). I quote selectively here:

> The value can be set to, respectively, the symbols ‘h:mm:ss’ or
>   ‘h:mm’, which means a duration is expressed as, respectively,
>   a "H:MM:SS" or "H:MM" string.

So adding this to the file:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq org-duration-format 'h:mm)
#+end_src
```

and evaluating it with `C-c C-c` will allow the clocktable to look like this:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 2
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2020-05-11 Mon 22:10]
| Headline     |    Time |
|--------------+---------|
| *Total time* | *27:00* |
|--------------+---------|
| A            |   23:00 |
| D            |    4:00 |
#+END:
```

You can also of course customize the variable if you want to avoid code.

Also, if you don't like the asterisks, you can customize the variable `org-clock-total-time-cell-format` whose default value is the string `*%s*`.